# Flutter Icons as Images?

Tags: flutter, fonts, material-design

Against my wishes, a client wants to custom make their own icons throughout the app I am building.  They are used to the web design world, and are furnishing me with a bunch of PNG images they hope we can use, just plopping them in.

Is this even possible?

Or is there a way for me to translate PNGs into a better asset that I can use like the Material design font glyphs?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens while replacing `Icon` widget with `Image.asset()`?

Comment: same question as Yeasin Sheikh

Comment: if you're worried about the size of the png files or don't want to use png for other reasons, you could use [flutter_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg). though does not make that much change in app size if you ask me but its svg

Comment: I figured using Glyph fonts was highly recommended, and using PNGs would be clunky? (My gut feeling is the PNGs will be much bigger, and not look as good scaled down, but I will try it out since you guys think it is viable) Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use PNGs, one way is like this:

First put your .png images in your application directory, e.g.,

```
.../pubspec.yaml
.../graphics/cool_icon.png
.../graphics/background.png
```

Then update your pubspec.yaml file like this:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - graphics/cool_icon.png
    - graphics/background.png
```

Then add the .png to your Widget:

```
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: _incrementCounter,
    tooltip: 'Increment',
    child: Container(
      width: 36.0,
      height: 36.0,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
            fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
            image: AssetImage('graphics/cool_icon.png')),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

[image: screenshot of code example]